# Is it possible for a 3ds to act as the source and destination of system transfers without having to wait 7 days in between?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I had three 3ds systems (two 3ds-xls and a 2ds) that me and my two kids use. Recently my older kid broke his 3ds-xl (he is unable to stop compulsively clicking the hinge back and forth as he plays, and it finally snapped off leaving the top screen connected to the bottom half of the unit by just a wire).

I bought a new 3ds-xl with the plan to transfer my (non-broken) 3ds-xl to that, then transfer my younger kid's 2ds to my old 3ds-xl, then transfer the older kid's broken 3ds-xl to the 2ds (so he won't have a hinge to break anymore). The order of transfers would look like this:

1. Non-broken 3ds-xl -> New 3ds-xl
2. 2ds -> Non-broken 3ds-xl
3. Broken 3ds-xl -> 2ds

The first transfer completed successfully, but I was unable to initiate the second one because the non-broken 3ds-xl said I had to wait 7 days. This is even though it acted as the source of the first transfer and needed to act as the destination for the second transfer. Is there any way around this? Presumably I will run into the same issue with the 2ds. Will it really take 14 days to complete this upgrade maneuvre?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a way to bypass the seven day restriction. Probably this prevents possible piracy and redistribution of games to multiple parties.

Comment: Did you try changing your time on your 3DS's?

Comment: You could have skipped one transfer by keeping your own 3ds, transferring your younger kid to the new one, and then transferring the older kid to the 2ds. That would have cut the time down to 7 days instead of 14 days.

Comment: I'm not really sure since I never had this happen to me, but what I think is that it should take long, but not as long as it says. Also, keeping in mind what Kadima said.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my recent testing, I couldn't find any way to do that. Changing the date doesn't affect anything, since the 3DS will have a tendency of detecting date changes as attempts to bypass something. Some games show it explicitly, such as Pokemon Picross, or Pokemon Shuffle, while other less used functions such as the System Transfer will only inform you when you attempt using it after such a change. If you aren't on transfer cool down, you're locked for 24 hours.

Comment: Well, this question is from 2 years ago.  I'm pretty sure he has solved the problem one way or another...